# ¿Cómo puedo borrar de la base de datos SQL, sus datos?

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy intentando borrar de datos de mi base de datos, sus datos, mediante *PHP*, pero no logro hacer que funcione:

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
    include('conexion.php');

    $conx = mysql_connect ("localhost","root","");
    if (!$conx) die ("Error al abrir la base <br/>". mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("odontologica") OR die("Connection Error to Database");  

    $reg= mysql_query("SELECT IdPaciente FROM paciente where 
    PNombre='$_POST[nombre]'",$conx);

    if($re=mysql_fetch_array($reg,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM paciente WHERE Nombre='$_POST[nombre]'",$conx);
        echo " 
            <p>El registro ha sido eliminado con exito.</p> 
           <p><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>VOLVER ATRÁS</a></p> 
        "; 
    }  
    else{
        echo " <p>El registro no ha sido eliminado</p> "; 
    }  

?>
```

El error es el siguiente:

> SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\wamp\www\prueba\delete.php on line 10

¿Cómo puedo borrar de la base de datos, sus datos?

Comment: Puedes hacer la eliminación directa sin la necesidad de hacer el `select`, o ¿acaso tienes varios pacientes con el mismo nombre?

Comment: **Uno de tus errores** es querer usar esto dentro de la consulta: `$_POST[nombre]`, para más claridad en el código siempre se aconseja recuperar las variables de `$_POST` en una variable, ejemplo: `$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];` luego usas simplemente la variable `$nombre...` te habrás fijado que `"nombre"` debe ir entre comillas en el POST. **Otro error más grave** es que usas una extensión obsoleta e insegura para manejar la BD. Y **otro error también grave** es que no uses consultas preparadas en las cuales pasas los valores del POST separados de la instrucción SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Hola intenta utilizar mysqli o pdo (seria lo mejor pdo) 
en ves de mysql para la conexion a la bd y el error es que pusiste "MYSQLI_ASSOC" cuando estas usando mysql no mysqli,saludos.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Has concatenado mal el string de la variable $reg, debería de ser así:
`$reg= mysql_query("SELECT IdPaciente FROM paciente where 
      PNombre='.$_POST['nombre'].'",$conx);`

Answer (score 0):

jajaj al final lo resolvi de esta manera

El registro ha sido eliminado con exito.

VOLVER ATRÁS

"; 
?>